# Local Srt files with AVPlayer

Tags: ios, avplayer, http-live-streaming, subtitle, srt

I'm trying to cache srt files and play them with mp4 video files using AVFoundation AVPlayer. 
Streaming works fine with webVTT subtitles but I also need to cache videos and subtitles.
I was wondering if this is even possible or a possible workaround exists?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: how were you able to manage to add subtitle to AVplayer?I also need it can you share!